# WPF Listbox Virtualization - How to Bring Item Into View

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, virtualization

I've got a listbox where I have to have virtualization on. I then have a map that has items plotted on it that need to have the feature of letting the user click on them. When they click on an item, I need to bring that item into view in the listbox.

The issue is virtualization. When I try to grab the container, it returns null, which makes sense, however what's the right thing to do? I've tried a few things such as `UpdateLayout()`, but I've yet to find the answer. Any ideas?

```
var container = lstItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(clickedItem);
if (container != null)
{
     var exp = container.Descendants().OfType<Expander>().FirstOrDefault();
     if (exp != null)
     {
          exp.IsExpanded = true;
          exp.BringIntoView();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListBox` gives you a method to do exactly this:

```
lstItems.ScrollIntoView(clickedItem);
```

If you insert that line above the code you've already shown, then `container` should give you an actual `ListBoxItem`.

However, if the item was out of view, the template probably hasn't been applied.  You can get around this by calling `container.UpdateLayout()` before searching for the `Expander`.

You'll still need the `exp.BringIntoView()` call, though, as the expander will presumably become larger once it's expanded, and the initial call to `ScrollIntoView` may not have brought it far enough into the viewport.  Alternatively, you could just call `ScrollIntoView` a second time.

Comment: ```exp``` returns null when the item isn't in the view. When I click it again (after the item is in view), ```exp``` is no longer null. Is ```UpdateLayout()``` the right way to fix this?

Comment: and by asking if it's "the right way," I mean, is it the proper way? It indeed fixes the issue, however I don't want to use it if there's a more performant way to accomplish it.